# weightsum not working in layouts even after 0dp set

Tags: android

i want my layout to be as shown in figure.so i am using weightsum.but design it self is not appear except realative layout with background color.what i am missing here?Please help me

[image]

code in xml file

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:background="#C5C5C5"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout

        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:id="@+id/signinBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_width="00dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/signinBtn" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
        android:layout_width="00dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: First thing is you didn't use `weightsum` anywhere, and why are you using such large value in `android:layout_weight`?

Comment: You have completely messed up weights concept. The view which has weightsum attribute doesn't have 0dp width but it's children have

Comment: Where is remaining 10 weight

Comment: @Vivek Mishra i have given it for space between two linear layout

Comment: You have to define that too it will not get assigned automatically

Comment: Weight doesn't work with relative layouts You have to use linear layout as parent to use weights

Comment: @Vivek Mishra thanks vivek this point i was not aware of.Now it is working

Comment: Will add this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parent layout should be linear layout to use weight like this

```
<LinearLayout
 android:weightSum="100"
 android:background="#C5C5C5"
 android:layout_height="60dp"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent">
 <LinearLayout 
 android:layout_weight="45"
 android:id="@+id/signinBtn"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner">
 <TextView 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Sign In"
 android:gravity="center" 
 android:padding="5dp" />
 </LinearLayout> 
<LinearLayout 
 android:layout_weight="10"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/signinBtn" />
 <LinearLayout 
 android:layout_weight="45"
 android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner">
 <TextView 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Cancel" 
 android:gravity="center" 
 android:padding="5dp" />
 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. the `weightSum` attribute must be declared inside the `LinearLayout`.
2. an `orientation` must be provided as well.
3. in your case the orientation is `horizontal` so all children must have `0dp` width.
4. don't forget to add `android:layout_weight` attribute to each child of the `LinearLayout`.

So i suggest changing your layout as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/signinBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```